# A quick way to change web servers

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

I have 2 CentOS Web Servers with 2 different hosts

- 1 is currently Live (`Server A`)
- The 2nd will replace the first (`Server B`)

Our domain currently points to `Server A`

In a normal scenario to switch between servers, we'd just simply update the DNS of the Domain to switch between servers. This action can obviously take up to 72hrs.

As we're launching a new Platform on the `Server B`, I'd like a contingency plan that allows me to switch between the 2 servers on-the-fly rather than waiting for a DNS to propagate. I don't have any experience with anything like load balancers, but could that help solve the issue by using a Config to switch traffic between the DNS and 2 Servers?

[image]

Any advice welcome for this scenario.

Edit: Re-worded question & Added example Flowchart

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. If this is for one application you normally have staging and live, so if you have two applications you would have four servers. Cloud and virtualisation may play a part in the solution, but I'm finding it tricky to understand what you're trying to achieve. You should look at reverse proxies though.

Comment: You could run something like keepalived on both systems, and make server B the master when the time is ripe.  B will then take over A's IP address.

Comment: Lower the TTL on the A/AAAA records down to something like one minute. That then allows you to flip between each server using DNS with one minute swap time. Once happy, you can up the TTL back to what it was.

Comment: @parkamark That was the first thing I considered, but you're still kinda relying on the hand-of-god.

Comment: @Craig I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I've done this before many years back when I had to physically re-locate a server on to a different network. I lowered the TTL days before the move, then moved the box, updated DNS, and everyone's site was back online instantly. Returned TTL to normal, job done.

Comment: @parkamark I gotcha. Just a bit nervous about a handful of DNS Servers not doing what they're told. I read that a low TTL can introduce some sort of lag, do you remember experiencing this?

Comment: If both servers are in the same network try to re-route the old IP to new server.

Comment: It will introduce "lag", because everyone will be querying your DNS servers often to get the current A/AAAA record settings. But the idea is you are sacrificing this "lag" with the ability to have a fail-safe fast rollback should things go wrong. You can't make an omelette without breaking some eggs, right?

Comment: Actually, Sunil's idea is a good one. Just do an IP swap between the two servers, if they are on the same network.

Comment: Swapping IPs with a script then? Otherwise it will take more than a minute so the low DNS TTL will sound as a better and safer solution. Also, if you don't want to rely on the DNS servers doing their job, maybe you should replace your DNS server software with better software? And why would you then rely on an extra piece of hardware/software as a man-in-the-middle solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, each ways have different level of certainty, risks and complexity. Some of these were covered in the comments.

- Reduce the TTL of the DNS record, several days before the move. Perform the move and then you can restore the TTL to its previous value. This does not guarantee all DNS servers in the world will have updated. You may still have some users operating off a stale DNS record. But that's what you get with DNS. It's generally good. But no guarantee. You can't even really verify as you would have to check all DNS servers of the world, many will be doing caching, some won't respect TTLs. But in generally, this is a pretty safe way to do it. Unless you have 10 million users or more, I think the potential risk is relatively low, that one of your users will be using a broken DNS server.
- Update both servers with the latest version, then it does not matter. Say A is currently the server pointed to by DNS, update B, change DNS, update A. There is a small possible problem window during the update of A where a user will get a broken site.
- Put a load balancer in front, which takes over the IP address DNS currently points to. This is a more complex change to your existing setup but is more how things should be generally.
- Quickly swap the IP addresses. Give Server B the IP address of Server A and change Server A. Very short downtime - a couple seconds if you are ready with a script. No risks of having stale DNS since you don't change DNS.
- Use Keepalived or similar tool. The DNS then points to a floating IP address. The server which currently has that IP would need to be given a different IP address. This is a higher complexity level than most other solutions, but it is a great improvement to your set up. Right now, you are at risk. DNS has a "long" TTL for the A record pointing to Server A. If Server A fails, you have to change the DNS to point to Server B which will take a long time to propagate. With a floating IP, then you never have to change the DNS. If Server A fails, Server B automatically takes over after a few milliseconds the floating IP and everything keeps on working.
- Update Server B with new code. Switch the configuration on Server A so that instead of serving the web site, the web server proxy the requests to Server B. (Easy if its Apache httpd, NGINX, IIS. Many others should be able to do that, if not, you could put HAProxy, quickly stop the web server and start HAProxy.) At this point, all the requests are handled by Server B on the new code. Change your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only web you are need to solve, why you don't just do 302 redirect in your main index file and then change your A/AAAA DNS records? Of course you could still change TTL at first, to not wait on DNS record change for such a long time, but 302 redirect will take effect immediately.

Solution with a load balancer is also not bad and it's not so hard to configure for example HAProxy, or NginX (or even Microsoft's IIS) in reverse proxy mode. You can test it on different port (let's say port 8080/4443) at first, and then switch it to port 80/443. But in LB solution there will probably be a short service drop-out, while you will changing your ports, because you would have to change your web server's port to something else from 80/443 on server A and use these ports for LB instead - it depend's on how quick you will be.

Or if both of your web servers are behind a firewall, there could possibly be a NAT port forwarding so you could only change the destination IP address from your server A to server B.